# White Point in Unity WebGL

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, unity-webgl

I am using Unity to build my WebGL app, so
Once I have it built I will upload it. There is a white point on the middle as shown below.

[image]

But when I test the game on the Unity SDK, the white point is never shown.

[image]

How do I remove the white point? Many Thanks.
Here is my setting.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It might be a part of html and not the actual game. Inspect your built game in browser tools to confirm what it is?

Comment: What is that background particle system? White round particles maybe? But also your background is using a particle alpha blend shader... If anything is behind it will bleed through.